# Should modules always contain a class?

Tags: python, module

I'm writing a module which only contains functions. Is it good practice to put these inside a class, even if there are no class arguments and the `__init__` function is pointless? And if so how should I write it?

Comment: There's  not much to be gained by putting them in a class and doing so would require ti have to be instantiated before they could be used. Just define the functions normally in the module script. Think of the module itself as a singleton instance (which it almost is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no particular reason to force functions to go inside a class if there's no reason to make a class. A python sourcefile already provide a perfectly reasonable *namespace* for storing similar, related functions. The [pypy](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/default/) implementation of the python programming language, for example, has many modules that don't have classes in them (for example, [`time`](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/default/pypy/module/time/interp_time.py)).

You would want a certain data structure as a class, of course, but there are certain behaviors that are entirely independent of data structures, and putting them in a class would just add needless complexity.

Answer (score 0):

It is good to build modules that contain a class for better organization and manipulation depending on how big the code is and how it will be used, but yes it is good to get use to building classes with methods in them. Can you post your code?